# How to download a multipart wav file from cloudant database and save locally using Node JS and REST API?

Tags: node.js, rest, https, cloudant

I am stuck in retrieving multipart from cloudant using Node JS API. Hence, I used REST API to download the wav file from cloudant database. But its not downloading wav file from https URL. When I enter the https URL directly in browser, it prompts me to save file locally. So, the URL is correct.

### Here is the code for REST API:

```
var request1 = require('request');
var filestream = fs.createWriteStream("input.wav"); 
var authenticationHeader = "Basic " + new Buffer(user + ":" + pass).toString("base64"); 

request1( { url : "example.com/data/1533979044129/female";, headers : { "Authorization" : authenticationHeader } }, 

function (error, httpResponse, body) { 

const statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode; 
httpResponse.pipe(filestream); 
httpResponse.on('end', function () { 
console.log("file complete"); 
filestream.close(); 
}); });
```

---

The file size of input.wav is 0. Its not downloading file. Please help.

Comment: save the file directly from the browser. check it's file format.

Answer (score 0):

Your callback has an `error` argument, which you are completely ignoring. Do something with this error, like print it out so your problem can tell you what you're doing wrong. I definitely see at least 1 problem in your source, and the error from `request` should tell you what it is.

**Edit** On second thought the above code shouldn't even execute. You should share code that you tested yourself. There's typos in there.

Comment: console.log(statusCode) prints 200.